# Is it possible to make a receiver app for chrome tab

Tags: google-cast, smart-tv, google-cast-sdk

I'm posting here because I didn't find any satisfying answer anywhere.

The question is quiet simple. I see a lot of application implementing the cast feature on Android. The issue is that even if I have a brand new smart TV, it actually doesn't support the cast feature of the majority of my apps.

For example, my TV has a Youtube app so I can cast youtube videos from the youtube app on my phone to my TV.

Now I would like to cast my favorite streaming app to my TV but my TV is not found. So I'm thinking, okay let's try to make an app for my TV that will receive that kind of command.

I know that I can make an app for my TV. Before starting that ambitious project, I want to be sure that the google cast sdk will allow me to write such receiver app.

Do you think this is possible ? Or do we really need one receiver app for every emitter app ?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube uses its own discovery protocol beyond what the Cast SDK supports. Apps need to integrate the Cast SDK in their senders and implement receivers that support their authentication and DRM.

Comment: So according to your comment, I just need to write an app that support the authentication and DRM of Chrome and this will enable my app to receive the cast request from a Chrome tab ? I think that it is not that simple or Google does not gives us the right materials to write such app. What do you think ?

Comment: The receiver app is launched on the Cast device once a user makes a connection from the sender. For Chrome, any web page that implements the sender logic will then allow its content to be played by its associated receiver.

Comment: Okay understood for the sender part. What about the "associated receiver" ? Is it possible to write a receiver that would respond to the cast standard request sent by Chrome when you use the "cast" feature in the options menu ?

Comment: Thats the way it works. You should go through the Cast documentation to understand how the Cast model works: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers

Comment: Well, I've already read some part of the documentation. While reading it again, I found this sentence which I think answer my question : "When you register your receiver application, you will receive the app ID to include in your sender's API calls". Because I'm not the maker of the sender (Chrome), the sender will never include my app ID. The only solution would be to get the app ID of the Chromecast device, I think this is not possible ...